# Rails Display Current Facebook Share Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I'm trying to display the current facebook share count in a Rails application. I keep getting the "can't convert string to text" error when trying to grab the current URL in my Rails app.

The code works if I put in something like facebook_shares("http://www.google.com") 
The code does not work if I use facebook_shares("#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}")

Not sure how to fix this problem

Here is my current code...

helper.rb:

```
def facebook_shares(url)
    data = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=#{URI.escape(url)}"))
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    data[url]['shares']
end
```

view.html.erb:

```
<% current_url = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}" %>
<%= facebook_shares(current_url) %>
```

When I run this I get a "can't convert string into integer" error. It works if I do the code below:

```
<% current_url = "http://www.google.com" %>
<%= facebook_shares(current_url) %>
```

Super lost...

Comment: give the full error stack please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This was a horrible oversight by myself :p.

I'm in development running on a local server, so I'm pulling localhost:3000/something.

Pushing this and running the function in production works fine. Sorry everyone, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`data[url]['shares']` part is suspicious. Eithere `data[url]` gives you Array and when you are trying `['shares']` on that Array you are getting the error,which is obvious. Or `data` itself is Array of something... Thus `data[url]` throws the error. So inspect first how data is looks like. This error is coming as [`Array#[]`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#%5B%5D-instance_method) don't allow string inside `[]`. See the below demo code:

```
arr = [1,2]
arr['foo']
# ~> -:2:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
# ~>  from -:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm not sure. It works when I pass in "http://anywebsite.com" but not when I'm trying to get the current url for that page on the rails app. This means that there must be something wrong with the "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}"